# How do you change the storage parameters of a already made table (sql developer)?

Tags: oracle, alter-table, storage, oracle-sql-developer

**Summarize the problem**
I have been given 6 tables that have all been created already and I was told to change the storage parameters of those tables. the issue I run into is that I can only change pctfree, pctused, initrans and max trans and not the others (initial, next, pctincrease and maxextents)

**Provide details and any research**

I have done a lot of research, yet some of them do not work with sql developer at all. Whilst the others do work but as stated only for the 4 storage parameters.

**When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried**

```
alter table CUSTOMERS
pctused 20 pctfree 80;
```

This works perfectly for those two, but I am unable to add the others. From what I found online, this was in fact the only thing that worked for me.

I appreciate all input!

Comment: Well those four parameters you mention don't apply to tables, only to tablespaces.

Comment: This helps me a lot, thank you so much. I am very new to this all.

Comment: Sounds like a homework or interview question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extent parameters can not be changed of an existing table, they are specified when a table is created. You can change them by reorganizing the table.

```
SQL> select INITIAL_EXTENT, NEXT_EXTENT, MAX_EXTENTS, PCT_INCREASE
     from user_tables where table_name = 'T1';

INITIAL_EXTENT NEXT_EXTENT MAX_EXTENTS PCT_INCREASE
-------------- ----------- ----------- ------------
         65536     1048576  2147483645

SQL>  alter table t1 storage(initial 1048576 next 2097152 maxextents 1073741822 pctincrease 1);
 alter table t1 storage(initial 1048576 next 2097152 maxextents 1073741822 pctincrease 1)
                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02203: INITIAL storage options not allowed


SQL> alter table t1 storage(next 2097152 maxextents 1073741822 pctincrease 1);
alter table t1 storage(next 2097152 maxextents 1073741822 pctincrease 1)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-25150: ALTERING of extent parameters not permitted


SQL> create table t2 storage (initial 1048576 next 2097152 maxextents 1073741822 pctincrease 1)
     as select * from t1;

Table created.

SQL> select INITIAL_EXTENT, NEXT_EXTENT, MAX_EXTENTS, PCT_INCREASE
     from user_tables where table_name in ('T1', 'T2');

INITIAL_EXTENT NEXT_EXTENT MAX_EXTENTS PCT_INCREASE
-------------- ----------- ----------- ------------
         65536     1048576  2147483645
       1048576     2097152  2147483645
```

Notice how the `MAX_EXTENTS` and `PCT_INCREASE` parameter did not change. They are relevant only for dictionary managed tablespaces, but that was forgotten ages ago, we use locally managed tablespaces.